# How to remove duplicates of a single character in string python?

Tags: python, string, duplicates

I have a string like this:

```
$$\\int_{-\\infty}^{\\infty}\\int_{-\\infty}^{\\infty}{{e^{(x+y)}}^2}dxdy$$
```

But what i want is:

```
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{e^{(x+y)}}^2}dxdy$$
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: So i want to remove every double backslashes and replase them with a single one

Comment: Please share the code you tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried with:
'''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(foo))'
But i want only remove the double backslash, this code eliminates every double character.

So '\\door' with my code will result '\dor'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if this is a string literal, then it will properly escape the slash, and you will get the result you want:

```py
print("$$\\int_{-\\infty}^{\\infty}\\int_{-\\infty}^{\\infty}{{e^{(x+y)}}^2}dxdy$$")
```

Otherwise, you could just replace the characters with one of it:

```py
string = "$$\\int_{-\\infty}^{\\infty}\\int_{-\\infty}^{\\infty}{{e^{(x+y)}}^2}dxdy$$"

string = string.replace(r'\\', '\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

input = "$$\\\\int_{-\\\\infty}^{\\\\infty}\\\\int_{-\\\\infty}^{\\\\infty}{{e^{(x+y)}}^2}dxdy$$"

output = re.sub("\\\\+", "\\\\", input)
print(output)
```

the backslash character must be duplicated because it is a special escape character. So the regex says to replace one or more occurrences of backslashes with a single one.